# Custom hotkey not working

Tags: interface

I have been trying to create Control Alt Command 1 as a shortcut for Append from Libary in Blender 2.93 and it is not working. It is the same one I used in 2.79. Can anyone say why?[image: User Preferences]

Comment: Works. Right-click the menu entry (*File > Append*) and choose *Assign Shortcut*, even assigning Ctrl+Option+1 is working for me on a mbp.

Comment: That worked. Thanks.